# Error 400 received when fetching from trovo API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I've been granted access to an API that uses OAuth 2, I've tried it with different API's and my requests were working.
However with the trovo API I seem to get error 400 at every endpoint.
I also get:

> "blocked by CORS policy: o 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

```
function fetching() {
  fetch("https://open-api.trovo.live/openplatform/validate", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "myKey",
        "Client-Id": "myID"
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.json());
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```

I also received a Client Secret not sure what to do with that.
Here is the documentation from Trovo: https://developer.trovo.live/docs/APIs.html

*Altogether I'm quite new to working with API's.*

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth flow requires a server, and cannot be done entirely on the front-end. In this example, you would need a server running somewhere other than StreamElements that would keep track of the access and refresh token.

You would then have the front end connect to the server to get the access token instead of directly to Trovo. Reason for this: security. To get the access token you need the private key, and you don't want to be sending that to the front end, or else they can do stuff as if they were you.

Even though stream overlays don't seem like a front end, it's most often just a browser being rendered, as if you just had a website open in chrome.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pZ3Nh8tgTE

Comment: Yes I've recieved the token.  Also I tried putting OAuth before the token, but didn't help, then I'm getting error 401 (Unauthorized) and the same CORS policy block.

Comment: If you are getting a CORS error, does mean you are using it on the front end? If so, that's where your error is. Due to security reasons, the whole OAuth flow is meant to take place on a backend server, where you can keep all the private keys and access tokens private. I would recommend you research a little more about how OAuth tokens work

Comment: I tried using it with StreamElements, so I can have https requests in my widgets. but I guess that is not permitted then.

Comment: Unfortunately not, stream widgets are front-end, and you would need a server running somewhere that would handle all the authentication. Should I make this into a full answer?

Comment: Well if you have the time, I'm not sure i understand completly how I could connect a widget to server that's running on SE server.

Comment: made an edit explaining in a bit more detail with some resources to learn more, hope it helps and that you learn a thing or two